# Generation vs Blood Potency question

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

My players and I were wondering about an aspect of Generation vs. Blood Potency.

It states on page 149 that character with a Generation of 10 gets a blood potency of 2. We were wondering if the +1 blood potency that the Ancillae gives increases the bp to 3?

If so why is it written on the page 137 recap that 10th and 11th generation have a bp 2. What if a generation 9 vampire sires a generation 10 in 2015… he would not be an Ancillae but would still get the base 2 bp right?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG Stackexchange! What a great first question! When you can please take a look at the [tour], and checkout the [help]. Hopefully you get a good answer!

Comment: I'll leave it here too in case you missed it; It looks like you've accidentally made two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way you can own your own question, and should be able to vote and mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

One change from earlier editions of **Vampire: the Masquerade** is the separation of Generation from Blood Potency and from the Background/Merit system. You get to choose your generation based on the kind of chronicle you're in — Childer, Neonate, or Ancilla. Characters of the 10th and 11th generation in an Ancilla game start with BP 2, and then add one, for BP3. If you were playing a 12th or 13th generation character in an Ancilla game — the situation you describe for your new embrace – they'd start at BP 1, and then add 1.

The character creation summary on pages 136-137 seems to include that bump; you'll notice it also has the extra advantages, flaws, bonus XP, and Humanity drop.

Answer (score 1):

### Generation

Generation is how far your vampire is from Caïn. That all.

### Blood potency

Blood potency is how much your blood is strong. It may depend on your generation, but some kindred of high generation can have it higher that some kindred of low generation.

### About your what if

Creation rules are here to tell a general case (which is kindred embraced in 2015 are most likely to be gen 13-16). You kinda break these rules by making an ancillae embrace someone in 2015. But let's say that it's the only rule you break, and you follow the rest of them, the neonate blood potency would be 2 (since it's the minimal value gen 10 vampire can get).

By the same logic, if you create a 13rd gen kindred embraced in the 18th century (so they are considered Ancilla at this point) following those rules, they would start with blood potency of 1 + 1 so 2.